# Share one module import among child processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, child-process

This issue came up while I was trying to work with sharding on my Discord bot with Discord.js. Each shard (at least in `process` mode) has it's own program executing, which means that different shards are effectively separate bots. One of my bot's features requires the user to use commands in a server as well as in DMs. The problem is that all DMs are sent to a single shard, so any users from a server on a different shard will have the command seem broken, because while the server's shard is keeping track of everything properly, the shard with the DMs is tracking a different set of servers and can't see any of that data.

I'm fairly new to sharding, and I thought the best way to fix this was to handle all of the information I'm tracking in a module imported into `index.js`, and then import the necessary parts into each `bot.js` child process shard so all of the data is consolidated into one place and every shard can access it. However, no matter how I set it up I kept getting strange promise rejections with no stack trace when I tried to import information from `index.js` (shard manager) to `bot.js` (code for the bot running on each shard).

This must be some sort of restriction on importing between child and parent processes, but I haven't been able to find any information on that. Does anyone know how to get imports working properly here, or a different method that would allow for centralized information handling so each shard can access it?

Comment: Can you show your code along with the error log please? It would be very helpful in solving this matter.

Comment: My code isn't exactly simple, and taking all of the code related to this command would make the question way too long. I will elaborate on exactly what the code is doing and provide error messages, though.

Comment: Hmm, I see, I don't think you need to import it to `index.js` where it's running the sharding (I don't think that's even possible), just add it to `bot.js` which will immediately import the same thing to all child proccesses. `so all of the data is consolidated into one place and every shard can access it.` if this is a config, then the above method should work, otherwise might wanna peek here before I suggest an answer - [Discordjs.guide - Gude - Sharding](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/additional-information.html). And if you can, the error code please :)

Comment: That's what I was doing originally, which gives each child process its own set of information to work with. I don't think I was clear in the question, but this is information and data being created in real time, so each process would have completely different sets of data because they're handling different servers. What I need is some way to keep track of this across all child processes so they all have access to the same information and can all manipulate said information.

Comment: No, you cannot share the same module in separate processes - they're separate environments! You need to explicitly let them communicate with each other.

Comment: [`client.shard.broadcastEval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/ShardingManager?scrollTo=broadcastEval)

Comment: Ah, I think you're right that broadcastEval() could be a solution to this. I had dismissed it before because it still didn't centralize everything, but as long as the data is in sync it doesn't need to be centralized. I'll try broadcastEval('data.push({...})') and see if I can get that working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That's what I was doing originally, which gives each child process its own set of information to work with. I don't think I was clear in the question, but this is information and data being created in real time, so each process would have completely different sets of data because they're handling different servers. What I need is some way to keep track of this across all child processes so they all have access to the same information and can all manipulate said information.

Then what you want to do is use [`client.shard.broadcastEval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/ShardingManager?scrollTo=broadcastEval). You can get a guild property from all clients cache by using:

```js
const getServer = async (guildID) => {
    // try to get guild from all the shards
    const req = await client.shard.broadcastEval(`this.guilds.cache.get("${guildID}")`);

    // return Guild or null if not found
    return req.find(res => !!res) || null;
}
```

[Example by ZiNc#2032](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/sharding)
Read more on sharding in these links:

- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Sharding](https://discordjs.guide/sharding)
- [Discordjs.guide - Guide - Sharding (Additional)](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/additional-information.html)
- [Discord.js.org - Docs - ShardingManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/ShardingManager)
- [Discord.js.org - Docs - ShardingManager#broadcastEval](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/ShardingManager?scrollTo=broadcastEval)
- [An Idiot's Guide - Guide - Sharding](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/sharding)